# How does 巨 resemble a hand (彐) holding a carpenter's square (工)?

Tags: glyph-origin

Left screenshot is from [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%B7%A8); right from [Richard Sears (Uncle Hanzi)](https://hanziyuan.net/#%E5%B7%A8).

[image]

I circled in green the lone [pictogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters#Pictograms) that most obviously pictures a hand holding a carpenter's square.

1. For productivity, I colored in red a semicircle in merely 3 of the pictograms, but this semicircle figures in the other pictogram. Are these semicircles intended to symbolize the human hand?
2. I still can't picture how these pictograms evolved to 巨.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The forms you're looking at are actually the ancestors of「矩」.「巨」was formed by cutting off the person.

---

The analysis starts from this form

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
伯矩盉蓋
[集成9412](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9412&jgwfl=)</kbd>

which depicts a *person*「大」holding a *tool*「工」.

> *Carpenter's square* is much too specific, and I would think that it is an over-interpretation.

- Exaggerate the person's hand to emphasise that the tool was held:

  <kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  伯矩卣
  [集成5228](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5228&jgwfl=)</kbd>
- Swap out「大」with the similar-meaning「夫」(*man*), and permanently detach part of the hand onto the tool:

  <kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  裘衛盉
  [集成9456](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9456&jgwfl=)</kbd>

The left hand side of the above character should now heavily resemble「巨」, which is created from omitting「大」or「夫」.

<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[語](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)5</kbd>
　
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[工部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=27)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

> 「夫」was later semantically corrupted into「矢」(*arrow > length, measurement*), forming「矩」.
>
> <kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> 桐柏廟碑</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)