# Is the official radical for 巨 “工” or “匚”?

Tags: radicals

In [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/34152/4709), we can clearly see the origin of 巨 is 矩, which is originally formed from 工 + 大 (corrupted into 矢). However, nowadays 巨 has lost the left hand side of 工, and so naturally the radical appears to be "匚".

Some dictionaries list 巨 as having `工`, and some as `匚` radical. For example, Hanping (using CC-EDICT) says it's 工, but Baidu (obviously not authoritative) and Pleco say it's 匚. Even some native speakers I talked to cannot agree whether it's 工 or 匚, and some say they were taught that it is 匚 very early in education.

Is there a fairly authoritative, widely accepted source on which radical 巨 falls under?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since radicals are dictionary headers, "what is the radical of X" is dependent on the dictionary you're looking at.

The most internationally-agreed-upon dictionary radicals for Chinese characters would be the [Kangxi Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangxi_Dictionary), which lists it under 「工」. Thankfully, most dictionaries have [sets of radicals which are derived from the Kangxi list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangxi_radical), and most dictionaries are in agreement with Kangxi's classification.

[image]

---

My edition of Pleco doesn't list the radical as 「匚」.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

first of all, **don’t fixated on regular script (楷書)**, read and think on bronze script or seal script; please.

look at the [components semantic tree (部件樹):](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%9F%A9)

矩 is 大 + 人 + 工

[image][image]

in the same page, the 漢語多功能字庫 stated clearly that

> 後來「大」形與「工」形分開，「大」(人形)的手部與「工」相連，形成「巨」字形

roughly, the “大” separated from “工”, only the “手” is connect to “工”; which make the character “巨”

[image]

this picture shown such separation :)

> 巨 has lost the left hand side of 工, and so naturally the radical appears to be "匚".

> Baidu (obviously not authoritative) and Pleco say it's 匚

only in regular script, that 巨 would appear belong to radical 匚 (radical 22), or 匸 (radical 23).

巨 in bronze script:

[image]

巨 in seal script:

[image]
[image]

these three clearly shown the “工“ in the character “巨”

> Is there a fairly authoritative, widely accepted source on which radical 巨 falls under?

as droooze said, the authoritative dictionary is 康熙字典

another one using 540 radicals is 說文解字. you may guess it, “巨” is in volume 5, (工, radical 147)

[image]

last, authoritative resources for etymology:

[漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)

[小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)

use the 漢語多功能字庫 first, compare the “pictures” of different scripts. **read** the etymologies (形義通解); these’re experts’ explanations in one place.

imo, it’s enough for novices, even advance users.

if one need a bigger pictures of characters in particular scripts, shift to 小學堂

have fun :)

Comment: @droooze , edited :) btw, don’t you think there’re more questions about etymology recently?

Comment: Lots of questions recently, but mostly from one person. Some of them are actually really fun questions, but would take too long for me to compile a bunch of convincing research :(

Comment: @droooze , yes, like a toddler asking about philosophy, astronomy or biology 

Comment: It's never too late to learn something challenging! I couldn't read any seals or 先秦 writings when I first joined this site, but that was just under 3 years ago

Comment: @droooze 工多藝熟，斯之謂也 